how can i connect to the sqlcipher file like 'D:/db.db3' in java，not android
I have a sqlcipher file locally, which is encrypted. How can I connect to it and dosomthing using java code? like execute sql,I tried a lot, but all failed.
I try this， but failed
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.44.1.0</version>
</dependency>

Help me!

You can try to use some open source tools and try to see if you can connect properly before you continue with what you are doing later.

SQLCipher for JDBC: https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/jdbc/
